# Arduino Nano does not upload sketch: No error information shown

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I recently fell over the issue that the Arduino Nano was not uploading the sketch (without providing error information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be resolved easily. Go to `Tools` --> `Processor` and set the bootloader to `ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)`. I already opened a Github issue to document this: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/9008